# SwiftUI navigationLink error - not accepting parameter on linked view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been exploring using maps in swiftUI and have added annotations from my data, however when I work with adding a navigation link into the annotations I receive an error -
*"Contextual closure type '() -> siteView' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body"*
problem is that siteView() does expect a Site to be passed through.

Question is - is there a way to resolve this and pass the site used to create the annotation through to the siteView() screen?

Code below:

```
struct siteMapView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var siteData: siteData

@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10))

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: siteData.sites) {
        MapAnnotation(coordinate: $0.locationCoordinate, anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)) {

            NavigationLink {
                siteView(site: $0)
            } label: {
                Circle()
                    .strokeBorder(Color.green, lineWidth: 10)
                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
            }
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
}
}
```

}

siteView code for completeness:

```
struct siteView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var siteData: siteData

var site: Site

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
    VStack {
        ZStack{
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://overseer.cyou/heritage/images/\(site.imageFile).jpg")) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .empty:
                ProgressView()
            case .success(let image):
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .clipped()
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            case .failure:
                Text("Failure")
                       Image(systemName: "photo")
            @unknown default:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
            VStack {
                Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text(site.name)
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                Text(site.country)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.black)
            //.opacity(0.2)
            }
    }
        Text(site.description)
        }
    }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: your `NavigationLink` signature is wrong. See this: 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink

for how to construct a `NavigationLink`. Typically its like this: `NavigationLink(destination: siteView(site: $0)) {
              Circle()
                    .strokeBorder(Color.green, lineWidth: 10)
                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
}`

Comment: Thanks for the input but even with that structure the error persists. It will link properly if the site is linked as a specific ie, Site: siteData.sites[23]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: siteData.sites) { site in
        MapAnnotation(coordinate: site.locationCoordinate, anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)) {

            NavigationLink {
                //      '$0' ↑
                //  you can't use '$0' here 
                //  siteView(site: $0)
                
                siteView(site: site)

            } label: {
                Circle()
                    .strokeBorder(Color.green, lineWidth: 10)
                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
            }
        }
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).